# How does nerdinner show map?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, nerddinner

I want to show few countries marked with "pin" much like what the nerddinner has:

http://nerddinner.com/

How can I achieve this functionality? Any details?

Comment: nerd dinner is available for download.. why not just look at the source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For detail you can check out this article : [Show Your Data on Google Map using C# and JavaScript](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-image/Google_map.aspx)
which provide little info about google map api which help you to achieve your task.

Comment: please note that the linked article uses a deprecated version of the Google Maps API...